# How do a repeat a query for past 30 days without union 30 times?

Tags: oracle

I have a query that returns a value for today (sysdate) but what is the best way to repeat the query for the past 30 days without creating 30 separate queries unioned together?

for example here is the basic query:

```
SELECT sum(duration)/3600
FROM IGN_OEE_EVENTS_D 
where asset_id = 1978 and event_type = 1 and shift = 2 and trunc(event_dt)=trunc(sysdate)
```

what I would like to avoid is repeating the query like this:

```
SELECT sum(duration)/3600
FROM IGN_OEE_EVENTS_D 
where asset_id = 1978 and event_type = 1 and shift = 2 and trunc(event_dt)=trunc(sysdate)
union
SELECT sum(duration)/3600
FROM IGN_OEE_EVENTS_D 
where asset_id = 1978 and event_type = 1 and shift = 2 and trunc(event_dt)=trunc(sysdate)-1
union
SELECT sum(duration)/3600
FROM IGN_OEE_EVENTS_D 
where asset_id = 1978 and event_type = 1 and shift = 2 and trunc(event_dt)=trunc(sysdate)-2
union
SELECT sum(duration)/3600
FROM IGN_OEE_EVENTS_D 
where asset_id = 1978 and event_type = 1 and shift = 2 and trunc(event_dt)=trunc(sysdate)-3
```

is there a way to do something like this?

```
REPEAT all dates where event_dt between sysdate and sysdate -30
SELECT sum(duration)/3600
FROM IGN_OEE_EVENTS_D 
where asset_id = 1978 and event_type = 1 and shift = 2
```

thank you.

Comment: Make the WHERE clause cover 30 days. Use a GROUP BY to establish group-per-day (the day group should also be a value selected), eg. `GROUP BY trunc(event_dt)`. Then the SUM will work over each group. There is no such thing as 'REPEAT' in Relational Algebra but filters can be used to select ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just need a `GROUP BY`.  I'm guessing that you also want an `ORDER BY`

```
SELECT trunc(event_dt), sum(duration)/3600
  FROM IGN_OEE_EVENTS_D 
 where asset_id = 1978 
   and event_type = 1 
   and shift = 2 
   and trunc(event_dt) >= trunc(sysdate)-30
 group by trunc(event_dt)
 order by trunc(event_dt)
```